# Wordpress modal login without redirect to wp-login.php page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, authentication

This is a crosspost from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175278/avoid-going-to-login-page-with-modal-login).

I would like to go straight to back end when I login on my modal login. What do I need to do to enable this, without using plugins. Do I need to use AJAX to display wp-login.php page?

Comment: http://natko.com/wordpress-ajax-login-without-a-plugin-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

in modal body just put the function name in php tag.

```
<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <?php wp_login_form(); ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

and you can find here in [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-bootmodal-login/) and look [demo](http://preview.alimir.ir/ajax-bootmodal-login-plugin/)